# HTTP request to login to certain website and check if it's valid

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, authentication, httprequest

I am trying to login to the website: https://secure.tibia.com/account/?subtopic=accountmanagement using `HTTPWebRequest` in C# WinForms. I currently do not know if it logged in or not. I want it to check if I did login or not.

When you enter an invalid username/password on the website, it displays an error message. Is there somehow a way to check if that error message appeared and then make a messagebox saying "Wrong login details!" ?

The string one could check is `The following error has occurred`. If that appears on the website after trying to login, we know it failed. Then it should make a messagebox with saying "login error" or something.

This is the code I am using so far. My username and password are stored in "account" and "password" variables. Note that I still do not know if this is the right way to login there. The username box is called "loginname" and the password "loginpassword". But I do not know if I am supposed to type it like that as in the code:

```
private void OnPostInfoClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string strAcc = account;
        string strPass = password;

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "loginname=" + strAcc;
        postData += ("&loginpassword=" + strPass);
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://secure.tibia.com/account/?subtopic=accountmanagement");

        myRequest.Method = "POST";

        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
        // Send the data.
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
 If (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "401")